# Broadcasting to Wowza Streaming Cloud

Tags: ios, swift, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I have an issue when trying to broadcast stream to Wowza Streaming Cloud from iOS device via GoCoder sdk. 
I setup Cloud Stream instance to use other RTMP as video source encoder and authentication is enabled. 
The workflow is following: 
1. I call Wowza Streaming Cloud API to start a stream, then setup GoCoder config with returned information.
2. Check Cloud Stream status via API, and when stream is started, immediately start broadcasting

And I receive a following error at this point
**Error Domain=com.wowza.gocoder.sdk Code=14 "An error occurred when trying to connect to host: "" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when trying to connect to host: }**

**EDIT** I enabled verbose log level for go coder sdk, and additional error info is **Socket connect with err = 36**

But if I start broadcasting to stream that was started 15 or more seconds ago, code works correctly.

Can you please give any advice what can cause a problem?

Comment: Please see my answer here:
[video streaming from iOS camera to wowza](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42943745/553071)

Comment: @dekeract  have you found solution for this ?

Comment: @dekeract any updates on this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @LandonAlder no, didn't find any solution for this. It seems like after stream is started, it takes some time to config connection to that stream. We moved from Wowza to own nginx rtmp server in the end. And we use [HaishinKit](https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift) as a streaming lib.

Comment: @dekeract thank you for the update! We ended up finding out this is an issue with wowza cloud and required us to ping the server repeatedly until we got a response. At that point, we knew we wouldn't see this error. We ended up switching to wowza server to mitigate this and a multitude of other issues in the end.

Comment: The same issue is occuring for me now. It works 15seconds, and now I have the "an error occurred when trying to connect to host:". I will move to https://socket.io/ as this problem occured since 2017, 3 years, with no solutions!!